# Similar Matrices and Conjugate Flows

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This question is an attempt to resuscitate and generalize [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536083/proving-that-flow-maps-are-conjugate), which lived one hour and was deleted by its author for reasons unknown.

The notion of [topological conjugacy of flows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy) is central to the theories of dynamical systems and ordinary differential equations, for it formalizes the concept that the orbit structure of two flows may be equivalent; that is, that the flows exhibit essentially the same behavior.  Specifically, we say that two flows $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$ on a topological space $X$ are *conjugate* when there exists a homeomorphism

$h:X \to X \tag 1$

such that for all $x \in X$ and $t \in \Bbb R$

$h(\phi_A(x, t)) = \phi_B(h(x), t). \tag 2$

A simple and particularly useful class of flows arises from linear time-invariant ordinary differential equations

$\dot x = Ax, \tag 3$

where we assume

$x \in \Bbb C^n \tag 4$

and

$A \in M(n, \Bbb C), \tag 5$

the set of square complex matrices of size $n$; the solution to (3) which takes the value $x(t_0)$ at $t_0$ is well-known to be

$x(t) = e^{A(t - t_0)}x(t_0); \tag 6$

thus the flow of (3) is given by

$\phi_A(x, t) = e^{At} x. \tag 7$

We recall that two matrices

$A, B \in M(n, \Bbb C) \tag 8$

are said to be *similar* if there exists a non-singular matrix

$T \in M(n, \Bbb C) \tag 9$

such that

$B = TAT^{-1}. \tag{10}$

***The Question*** is then:

Show that there is a linear homeomorphism

$T: \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C^n \tag{11}$

conjugating $\phi_A(x, t)$ and $\phi_B(x, t)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are $T$-similar, that is,

$B = TAT^{-1}. \tag{12}$

If $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, must $T$ also be real?

***Note Added in Edit, Saturday 8 February 2020, 11:25 AM PST:***  In light of Conifold's comment, we see that the existence of a suitable real $T$ gives rise to a purely imaginary matrix $iT$ which also satisfies the requisite conditions.  Therefore I modify my closing question above and ask

If $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, must $T$ be either purely real or purely imaginary?

***End of Note.***

Comment: It is trivial that a $T$ conjugates the generators iff it conjugates the flows, differentiate $e^{tA}$ in one direction and use the series for it in the other. And if some $T$ works then so does $iT$, so it mustn't be real.

Comment: I'm a bit thrown off by the notation. Why is the flow written the form $x e^{At}$ rather than $e^{At}x$, which is what I would expect for $x \in \Bbb C^n$ (where $x$ is interpreted as a column vector, as is typical)?

Comment: Perhaps it is worth to point out that there exists a diffeomorphism conjugating $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are conjugate (of course, this is obvious in one of the directions).

Comment: @Lmidh:  right it was supposed to be $\Bbb C$.  Fixed it. Were you the one whose edits I rejected?  If so, sorry you were right but I kept seeing $C$ and $\Bbb C$ as the same 'til I took a close look.

Comment: @Lmidh:  you don't have to delete them as far as I am concerned,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll stick to the convention that $x$ is a column vector so that matrices appear on the left, which seems contrary to some parts of this post. The more difficult direction of the two (I think) is to show that if a linear homomorphism  $T$ exists, then $A$ and $B$ must satisfy $B = TAT^{-1}$.

So, suppose that $T$ is such that for all $x \in X = \Bbb C^n$ and $t \in \Bbb R$, we have
$$
T\phi_A(x,t) = \phi_B(Tx,t) \tag{1}
$$
where
$$
\phi_A(x,t) = e^{At}x, \qquad \phi_B(x,t) = e^{Bt}x. \tag{2}
$$
Plugging (2) into (1) yields the equation
$$
Te^{At} x = e^{Bt}Tx, \tag{3}
$$
which holds for all $x \in X$ and $t \in \Bbb R$.  Because (3) holds for all $x$, we see that for any given $t \in \Bbb R$, $Te^{At}, e^{Bt}T$ induce the same linear operator which means that they must be the same matrix.  That is, we have $Te^{At} = e^{Bt}T$ for all $t$.

Now, note that
$$
\begin{align}
Te^{At} &= T e^{T^{-1}(TAT^{-1}t)T} = 
T [T^{-1}e^{TAT^{-1}t}T] = e^{(TAT^{-1})t} T.
\end{align}
$$
So, we can now state that $e^{(TAT^{-1})t} T = e^{Bt}T$ holds for all $t$.  By the invertibility of $T$, this implies that $e^{(TAT^{-1})t} = e^{Bt}$ holds for all $t$.  It can now seen in a few ways that $TAT^{-1} = B$; I think that the most natural is to note that 
$$
\left. \frac{d}{dt} e^{Mt} \right|_{t=0} = M e^{M\cdot 0} = M.
$$
So since the functions $e^{(TAT^{-1})t}, e^{Bt}$ are equal for all $t$, they're derivatives at $t = 0$ must coincide so that $TAT^{-1} = B$, as was desired.

Comment: Thanks for the most excellent answer.  You were right, I should have set $\phi_A(x, t) = e^{At}x$; don't know why I slipped on that one  May very well edit the question.  Thanks again, ***+1!!!***

Comment: @RobertLewis You're welcome.  I was wondering if maybe there was some convention here that I wasn't aware of but I guess we're all good.

Comment: Have you perchance anything you might like to add concerning whether $T$ must be purely real, purely imaginary, or neither?  See the new, recently edited version of my question.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertLewis If a real matrix $T$ works, then so does the matrix $e^{i\theta}T$ for any real $\theta$, so $T$ need not be purely real or imaginary.  An interesting point, though, is that if two real linear flows are conjugate via a complex transformation $T$, then there must also exist a real conjugating transformation.

Comment: Hmmmm . . . how to see that?  I guess by looking at the real and imaginary parts of $TAT^{_1} = B$ for real $A$, $B$ and complex $T$?  Maybe?

Comment: @RobertLewis It comes down to the fact that if $TAT^{-1} = B$ for some complex $T$ and real matrices $A,B$, then the same must hold for some real $T$.  I actually don't know of a quick way to see that.  One approach is to show that since $A$ and $B$ are similar to each other via a complex $T$, they must be similar to the same real canonical form, and every real matrix is similar to its real canonical form via a real transformation.

Comment: Something to think about.  Thanks!

Comment: How do you show that if A and B are equivalent then they are topologically conjugated?

Comment: @BenGrossmann How do you show that if A and B are equivalent then they are topologically conjugated?

Comment: @AGL I'm not sure what you mean when you say that $A$ and $B$ are "equivalent" or "topologically conjugated".